# 'int' object is not subscriptable - Python using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Im working with nested JSON data with Pandas, but i have a problem once i extract the dataframe of the nested data.

The data looks like:

```
[{"export_id":"COL-EXP-1894","origin_office":"EXAMPLE","destination_office":"","incoterms":"","shipment_date":"","export_date":"2023-01-01","origin_port":"Buenaventura","destination_port":"New York/New Jersey","bl_number":null,"shipping_line":null,"shipping_mode":null,"vessel_name":null,"voyage_number":null,"reservation_number":null,"container_number":null,"seal_number":null,"eta":null,"etd":null,"export_status":"in_progress","ico_list":\[\]}\]
```

And reading like that all is good, but some data have ico_list like:

```
[{"export_id":"COL-EXP-1894","origin_office":"EXAMPLE","destination_office":"","incoterms":"","shipment_date":"","export_date":"2023-01-01","origin_port":"Buenaventura","destination_port":"New York/New Jersey","bl_number":null,"shipping_line":null,"shipping_mode":null,"vessel_name":null,"voyage_number":null,"reservation_number":null,"container_number":null,"seal_number":null,"eta":null,"etd":null,"export_status":"in_progress","ico_list":[{"ico_id":"03-0178-436-23","contract_id":"CI-1046","customer":null,"origin_office":"example","destination_office":"example","incoterm":"CIF","quality":"ML","mark":"example","packaging_type":"Nitrogen-Flushed Vac-Packed Boxes - 35KG","packaging_capacity":35.0,"units":1,"quantity":35.0,"certification":null}]}]
```

And not just one like the example, can be more, so i implemented this:

```
if response.status_code == 200:
        data_str = response.text
        try:
            atlas_api_data = json.loads(data_str)
            df_atlas = pd.json_normalize(atlas_api_data)
            #print(df_atlas)
        except:
            print('ErrorOccured While Parsing JSON ATLAS API TO Dataframe')
        df_atlas2 = pd.json_normalize(df_atlas['ico_list'].loc[95])

    for i, row in df_atlas.iterrows():
        export_id = row['export_id']
        origin_office = row['origin_office']
        destination_office = row['destination_office']
        export_date = row['export_date']
        origin_port = row['origin_port']
        destination_port = row['destination_port']
        bl_number = row['bl_number']
        shipping_line = row['shipping_line']
        shipping_mode = row['shipping_mode']
        vessel_name = row['vessel_name']
        voyage_number = row['voyage_number']
        reservation_number = row['reservation_number']
        container_number = row['container_number']
        seal_number = row['seal_number']
        export_status = row['export_status']
        values = [export_id,origin_office,destination_office,export_date,origin_port,destination_port,
            bl_number,shipping_line,shipping_mode,vessel_name,voyage_number,reservation_number,container_number,
            seal_number,export_status]
        data_list.append(values)
        df_atlas2 = pd.json_normalize(df_atlas['ico_list'].loc[i])
        if df_atlas2.empty:
            print('Empty DF')
        else:
            for row_ico, j in df_atlas2.iterrows():
                ico_id = row_ico['ico_id']
                contract_id = row_ico['contract_id']
                customer = row_ico['customer']
                incoterm = row_ico['incoterm']
                quality = row_ico['quality']
                mark = row_ico['mark']
                packaging_type = row_ico['packaging_type']
                packaging_capacity = row_ico['packaging_capacity']
                units = row_ico['units']
                quantity = row_ico['quantity']
                certification = row_ico['certification']
                ico_values = [export_id,ico_id,contract_id,customer,incoterm,quality,mark,packaging_type,packaging_capacity,units,quantity,certification]
                data_ico_list.append(ico_values)
```

In this way i extract only the data that i need, and for the first level worked, but when i go to the second iterrows() it says

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [4], line 43
     41 else:
     42     for row_ico, j in df_atlas2.iterrows():
---> 43         ico_id = row_ico['ico_id']
     44         contract_id = row_ico['contract_id']
     45         customer = row_ico['customer']

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

When printing the df_atlas2 it looks normal, like this:
[variable: df_atlas2 before goes into iterrrows()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrMq7.png)

I tried using `df_atlas2['ico_id'].astype(str)` with all the columns and `ico_id = str(row_ico['ico_id'])` but still getting the message

If you know how to solve this, hundred thanks!

Comment: `for row_ico, j` This is the wrong order. Pandas puts the row key first. It should be `for j, row_ico`.

Comment: `for row_ico, j in df_atlas2.iterrows()` - shouldn't index go first?

Comment: Both of you are right, im blind. Thanks!